# Connection String error on VB net 2008 and MySQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I try to get some data from MySql using Visual Studio .Net 2008 and on this particular connection string it gives me error that input string was not in a correct format.

```vb
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class Form1
    Dim Scaderea As String = "SELECT `No`,`Laps`,`Lap_Tm`, ((SELECT `Lap_Tm` from `raw` where `No` = 7 AND (`Lap_Tm`<>"""") AND `Laps`=1) - `Lap_Tm`) AS 'Diferente' FROM `raw` WHERE `No`=7 AND (`Lap_Tm`<>"""") AND Laps!=1 AND Laps>1"

    Public Const cs As String = "server=************;User Id=**********;PASSWORD=**********;port=3306;Persist Security Info=True;database=circuit;Convert Zero Datetime=True;Allow Zero Datetime=True"

    Public rdr As MySqlDataReader = Nothing
    Public con As MySqlConnection = Nothing
    Public cmd As MySqlCommand = Nothing

    Private Sub Button1_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        DataGridView3.Rows.Clear()
        DataGridView3.SuspendLayout()
        'MsgBox(Scaderea)
        Try
            con = New MySqlConnection(cs)
            con.Open()
            cmd = New MySqlCommand(Scaderea, con)
            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

            While (rdr.Read())
                MsgBox(rdr.Item(0))
                Dim Nr_Conc = rdr("No").ToString
                Dim Tur = rdr("Laps").ToString
                Dim Timp = rdr("Lap_Tm").ToString
                Dim Diferenta = rdr("Diferente").ToString
                DataGridView3.Rows.Add(Nr_Conc, Tur, Timp, Diferenta)
            End While
            con.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then con.Close()
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Finally
            con.Close()
            con.Dispose()
        End Try
        DataGridView3.ResumeLayout()
    End Sub
End Class
```

On PHPmyadmin the syntax is working

```sql
SELECT `No`, `Laps`, `Lap_Tm`, (( SELECT `Lap_Tm` FROM `raw` WHERE `No` = 7 AND ( `Lap_Tm` <> "" ) AND `Laps` = 1 ) - `Lap_Tm` 
) AS 'Diferente' 
FROM
    raw 
WHERE
    `No` = 7 
    AND ( `Lap_Tm` <> "" ) 
    AND Laps != 1 
    AND Laps >1
```

and the result is:

```
"7" "2" "00:02:46.853"  "5.129"
"7" "3" "00:02:51.203"  "0.779"
"7" "4" "00:02:45.291"  "6.691"
```

Comment: I hope these are not your actual credentials for your database!

Comment: lol never mind!

Comment: On which line do you get the error?

Comment: can you change value of Scadera Dim Scaderea As String = "SELECT `No`,`Laps`,`Lap_Tm`, ((SELECT `Lap_Tm` from `raw` where `No` = 7 AND (`Lap_Tm`<>'') AND `Laps`=1) - `Lap_Tm`) AS 'Diferente' FROM `raw` WHERE `No`=7 AND (`Lap_Tm`<>'') AND Laps!=1 AND Laps>1"

Comment: the error raise after rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

Comment: @Topo_AS that means  your sql query syntax has problem, you given double quote in not equal pharse, it create problem .thats why suggest use my comment in place of your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by modify the interrogation syntax to:

```
Dim Scaderea As String = "SELECT No, Laps, TIME_FORMAT(Lap_Tm, ""%H:%i:%S.%f"") AS 'timp1', TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(ABS(( SELECT Lap_Tm FROM raw WHERE NO = 7 AND ( Lap_Tm <> '' ) AND Laps = 1 ) - Lap_Tm )) , ""%H:%i:%S.%f"") AS 'timp2' FROM raw WHERE No = 7 AND ( Lap_Tm <> '' ) AND Laps > 1"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always compare your connection string with the one found on [www.connectionstrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/). In this particular case you have a few incorrect spellings:

- `UserId` needs to be `Uid`
- `Password` needs to `Pwd`
- `Convert Zero Datetime` needs to be `ConvertZeroDatetime`

Comment: yes but is the same. because other interrogations works Like ````Dim max_lap As String = "SELECT MAX(LAPS)  AS 'maxi_lap' FROM raw WHERE CAST(LAPS as SIGNED INTEGER)"````

Comment: So then are you saying your connection string is in an invalid format or your SQL command is in an invalid format?

Comment: the error apear when While (rdr.Read()) runs and error is ````input string was not in a correct format````

Comment: This would indicate an error in your SQL command. If you take the SQL and plug it directly into phpMyAdmin do you get a similar error?

Comment: @Topo_AS could you elaborate as to what you are trying to achieve with your query?